# What are the ways to inject custom service instead of third-party plugin's service without having source code of that pugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Asp.Net MVC application which has PictureService having imageurl that accept full image url. But only relative url need to send because of some security reason. Also MVC application contains third-party plugin which also contains same PictureService & it also requires full image url.

So, Is it possible to inject relative url instead of full image url into third-party plugin service? Also I don't have source-code of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only when you're knowing that third party plugin uses which services, and if that service can be override, then you can simply override that service and pass whatever URL you want to add.